# Need solution for creating search textbox of a JSON table using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I just begin to work with javascript and jquery and sort of clueless about everything.

This is my json converted from a model

```
changeData = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));
```

The content looks like this:

```
changeData = [ 
{"RemoteRoute":{"Id":1,"Code":"1","Name":"Route1a","Outward":true,"Detail":null},"LocalRoute":null,"Change":"New"}, 
{"RemoteRoute":{"Id":1,"Code":"1","Name":"Route1b","Outward":false,"Detail":null},"LocalRoute":null,"Change":"New"}, 
{"RemoteRoute":{"Id":2,"Code":"2","Name":"Route2a","Outward":true,"Detail":null},"LocalRoute":null,"Change":"New"}, 
{"RemoteRoute":{"Id":2,"Code":"2","Name":"Route2b","Outward":false,"Detail":null},"LocalRoute":null,"Change":"New"}]
```

which I use to create a table

```
for (var item in changeData){ 
        var tr=$('<tr onclick=\"ShowChange(' + no + ');\" class=\"childDiv\"></tr>');
        outward = changeData[item].RemoteRoute.Outward;
        code = changeData[item].RemoteRoute.Code;
        name = changeData[item].RemoteRoute.Name;
        change = changeData[item].Change; 

        $('<td>'+ code          +'</td>').appendTo(tr);
        $('<td>'+ name          +'</td>').appendTo(tr);
        $('<td>'+ change        +'</td>').appendTo(tr);
        tr.appendTo('.displaytable');  
    };
```

I'm trying to create a search box (for 'name') with ajax. However as I stated above, I'm completely clueless from here.

Could anyone please suggest me some approachs I may take. An example would be great. Thanks so much!

Comment: So this code world perfectly, but you need to add option to search based on name field? do you want to search (send a request to the server) of filter the table (using client side)?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to make a client side filter based on name field.

Comment: I suggest you to use jquery plugin to archieve what you want. [jqGrid][1] will be great for you.
[1]: http://www.trirand.com/blog/

Answer (score 0):

Change your code a little so that you have a td with the name as the id. This way you will then be able to add some jquery to itterate through the td collections looking for that name id. Then it'd be a case of showing or hiding the desired rows.

```
for (var item in changeData){ 
    var tr=$('<tr onclick=\"ShowChange(' + no + ');\" class=\"childDiv\"></tr>');
    outward = changeData[item].RemoteRoute.Outward;
    code = changeData[item].RemoteRoute.Code;
    name = changeData[item].RemoteRoute.Name;
    change = changeData[item].Change; 

    $('<td>'+ code          +'</td>').appendTo(tr);
    $('<td id="' + name + '">'+ name          +'</td>').appendTo(tr);
    $('<td>'+ change        +'</td>').appendTo(tr);
    tr.appendTo('.displaytable');  
};
```

jQuery:

```
$('#txtBoxIDUsedToFilterByName').keyUp(function(){
    var searchTerm = $(this).val();
    $('.displaytable > tr > td').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('id:contains("' + searchTerm + '")')
            $(this).closest('tr').show();
        else
            $(this).closest('tr').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Absolutly right Johan thanks man. Sorry just wrote that off the top of my head. Should do some error checking before posting really

Comment: Np, but i think you need to use it like this (assuming you have a class for the name td): `$('.displaytable > tr > td.name:contains("'+ serchTerm +'")').each(function(){ });`. Dont use id. it needs to be unique.

Comment: Again true. I was trying to keep it easy to understand for a novice but yeah that would make more sense in the long run although wouldn't stop the query from running correctly at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I would have done something like this:

```
$(function(){

    $.each(changeData, function(k, v){

         var $tr = $('<tr>' +
                         '<td class="name">'+ v.RemoteRoute.Name+'</td>' + 
                         //add all the tds here
                     '</tr>')
                     .click(function(event){
                          //handle the <tr> click here
                     })
                     .hide() //hide the row
                     .attr({ 'class': 'childDiv' }); 
                     //addClass() is another options

    });

});
```

But could you elaborate the search part? Would you like all rows to be hidden, and show only the rows that have mathing names (compared to the textbox)? In that case:

```
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){

    var searchText = $(this).val();

    $('table tr td.name').filter(function(){ 
        return $(this).text().indexOf(searchText) !== -1;
    })
    .closest('tr')
    .show();

    //show the closest tr if searchtext matches the name

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this Example:

I have created an input text and a table

```
<input id="namefilter" type="text" />
<table id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Change</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Code 1</td>
        <td>Dan Poter</td>
        <td>Change 1</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Code 1</td>
        <td>Name 1</td>
        <td>Change 1</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Code 1</td>
        <td>Bred Pit</td>
        <td>Change 1</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Code 1</td>
        <td>Don Joun</td>
        <td>Change 1</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Code 1</td>
        <td>Pitter</td>
        <td>Change 1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Next the jquery code

```
$("#namefilter").keyup(function(event) {
   var textToFilter = $(this).val();
    var table = $('#mytable');
                table.find('tr').each(function (index, row) {
                    var allCells = $(row).find('td:nth-child(2)');
                    if (allCells.length > 0) {
                        var found = false;
                        allCells.each(function (index, td) {
                            var regExp = new RegExp(textToFilter, 'i');
                            if (regExp.test($(td).text())) {
                                found = true;
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                        if (found == true) {
                            $(row).show("fast");
                        } else {
                            $(row).hide("fast");
                        }
                    }
                });
});
```

You can easily set it to filter based on all the columns in the table by changing the following line:

```
var allCells = $(row).find('td:nth-child(2)');
```

To:

```
var allCells = $(row).find('td');
```

[Fiddel example](http://jsfiddle.net/YaRJW/1/)